# Passing Java command-line arguments when using -cp

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I'm writing a simple batch script to execute a game quicker (for a dev environment purpose), however I seem to be unable to pass the appropriate command-line arguments to the executable:

```
@ECHO OFF

set USERNAME=Testing
set MCDIR=%APPDATA%/.minecraft/
set GAMEDIR=%MCDIR%/versions/1.7.5/
set NATIVES=%GAMEDIR%/natives/

java -client -Xmx512M -Xms512M ^
-Djava.library.path=%NATIVES% ^
-cp %GAMEDIR%/1.7.5.jar:^
%MCDIR%/libraries/java3d/vecmath/1.3.1/vecmath-1.3.1.jar:^
%MCDIR%/libraries/net/sf/trove4j/trove4j/3.0.3/trove4j-3.0.3.jar:^

##etc... lots of libs

%MCDIR%/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/lwjgl_util/2.9.1/lwjgl_util-2.9.1.jar:^
%MCDIR%/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/lwjgl-platform/2.9.1/lwjgl-platform-2.9.1-natives-windows.jar:^
%MCDIR%/libraries/net/java/jinput/jinput-platform/2.0.5/jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar:^
net.minecraft.client.main.Main --username=%USERNAME% --version 1.7.5 --gameDir %MCDIR% --assetsDir %MCDIR%/assets --userProperties {} --accessToken Offline

pause
```

However this small script seems to fail the instant it goes beyond `client.main.Main` with any argument, effectively treating it as a JVM argument rather than a command-line program argument. Is there a different way to go about doing this when using `-cp` rather than `-jar` for calling a program in java? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there is no space between the end of your path (the last `^`) and your `Main` class, so your `Main` class is effectively part of the `-cp` JVM argument.  There is no class yet, so `java` still sees JVM args.

Try putting a space after the last part of the `-cp` value and your `net.minecraft.client.main.Main`, to separate the `-cp` value and your class on the command line.

Comment: It might also be worth removing the final colon on the last intended element in the classpath.

Comment: Strange, my new error around this is "Could not find main class `net.minecraft...etc`, but I just threw the 1.7.5 jarfile used above into jd-gui, and it's definitely there. Is there still something wrong with the script?

Comment: Found the other issue, was using colons instead of semicolons